# Nullable boolean in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, boolean, nullable

I'm trying to set a array with a null in to a boolean, but I dont know how to do it, here is my code

```
export interface PeriodicElement {  
caja: boolean;
tractor: boolean;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
{caja:null, tractor:false}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union types to achieve this.

[Union Types - Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

> The first way to combine types you might see is a union type. A union type is a type formed from two or more other types, representing values that may be any one of those types. We refer to each of these types as the union’s members.

```
export interface PeriodicElement {  
   caja: boolean | null;
   tractor: boolean | null;
}
```